# Codeigniter not retrieving from database after id = 15

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter.
And for some reason, it stops working correctly after my datbase id passes 15. See my code below

So after my $_POST['id'] passes 15, my foreach loop is just not working. So 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 etc are working fine.

```
function get_item_info(){

    $this->db->select('*')->from('producten')->where('productnr', $_POST['id']);
    $this->db->join('merken', 'merken.id = producten.productnr');       

    $query = $this->db->get();

    foreach($query->result() as $row)
    {
         echo '<h2>'.$row->merk .'&nbsp;'. $row->productnaam . '</h2>';
         echo '<h4>Kleur: '.$row->kleur.'</h4>';
         echo '<h4>Gewicht:'.$row->gewicht.'G </h4>';
         echo '<h4>Op voorraad?: Ja </h4>';
         echo '<h4>Levering: Binnen 2 werkdagen </h4>';
         echo '<h4><b>Prijs: €'.$row->prijs. '</b></h4>';
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing my join which was wrong.